# Binary Search Algorithm - Project Ideas

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

I'm writing a python project about binary search,  but I would like to be able to implement a graphical interface for this algorithm.
Do you have any ideas how I could use this algorithm so that I can implement the interface?
I mean project ideas , not the implementation itself ..

Thank you

This is my code :

````
# It returns index of x in given array arr if present,
# else returns -1
def binary_search(arr, x):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0
 
    while low <= high:
 
        mid = (high + low) // 2
 
        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        if arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1
 
        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            high = mid - 1
 
        # means x is present at mid
        else:
            return mid
 
    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    return -1
 
 
# Test array
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ]
x = 10
 
# Function call
result = binary_search(arr, x)
 
if result != -1:
    print("Element is present at index", str(result))
else:
    print("Element is not present in array")```
````

Comment: You can dynamically (in time) draw search tree, similar like visualization [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#/media/File:Binary_Search_Depiction.svg).

Comment: Are you drawing ASCII art or are you going to implement a real UI framework?

Comment: The point is it's a college project  and my professor is asking for a graphical interface for this .. so yeah, I'm going to implement a real UI framework with buttons and stuff.

Comment: Just for fun I implemented ASCII-art graphics in console in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412809/941531), please put a look, maybe it will give you some useful ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you asked for graphical interface, still just for fun I decided to implement following simple ASCII-art visualization for your task of Binary Search, it might be useful for you to give you some ideas.

I used some [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) when drawing graphics into console. This escape codes on Windows needs installing one time `colorama` module `python -m pip install colorama`. On Linux it doesn't need installing anything.

Code can be tweeked to different random seed value or amount of numbers or size of numbers (up to 100, up to 1000, etc). Values are chosen randomly with fixed seed value (change value in `random.seed(...)` line).

First I show ASCII-video screencast recorded on my Linux ([asciinema link](https://asciinema.org/a/412231)), then code:

[image]

**Code**:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67412587#main.py)

```
import platform, time, sys
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import colorama
    colorama.init()

def vis(data, steps):
    def str_set(s, i, c):
        return s[:i] + c + s[i + 1:]
    def astr_set(a, j, i, c):
        a[j] = str_set(a[j], i, c)
    dlen = max(len(str(e)) for e in data) + 1
    loline = ''.join(str(e).zfill(dlen - 1) + '|' for e in data)
    ll = len(loline)
    N = len(steps)
    h1 = 3
    lines = [' ' * ll for e in range(h1 * N)] + [loline]
    def emit_frame():
        sys.stdout.write("\033[F" * len(lines) + '\n'.join(lines) + '\n')
        time.sleep(1)
    emit_frame()
    for i in range(N - 1):
        lpcur, lpnext = [dlen * steps[i + e] + (dlen - 2) // 2 for e in (0, 1)]
        for j in range(h1 - 1):
            astr_set(lines, i * h1 + j, lpcur, '|')
        dir_ = -1 if steps[i + 1] < steps[i] else +1 if steps[i + 1] > steps[i] else 0
        for j in range((i + 1) * h1, len(lines) - 1):
            astr_set(lines, j, lpcur, '.' if j < len(lines) - 2 else '?')
        for j in range(lpcur, lpnext + dir_, dir_):
            astr_set(lines, (i + 1) * h1 - 1, j, ('/' if dir_ < 0 else '\\') if j in (lpcur, lpnext) else '-')
            if j == lpcur:
                emit_frame()
        if i == N - 2:
            for j in range((i + 1) * h1, len(lines) - 1):
                astr_set(lines, j, lpnext, '|' if j < len(lines) - 2 else 'V')
            emit_frame()

def binary_search(f, l, r, target):
    steps = []
    while l <= r:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        steps.append(m)
        fm = f(m)
        if fm < target:
            l = m + 1
        elif fm > target:
            r = m - 1
        else:
            break
    return steps

def main():
    import random
    random.seed(3)
    data = sorted(random.randrange(100) for i in range(30))
    target = data[random.randrange(len(data))]
    steps = binary_search(lambda x: data[x], 0, len(data) - 1, target)
    vis(data, steps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Final output:

```
                                          |                                               
                                          |                                               
                                          \-----------------------\                       
                                          .                       |                       
                                          .                       |                       
                                          .                       \-----------\           
                                          .                       .           |           
                                          .                       .           |           
                                          .                       .     /-----/           
                                          .                       .     |     .           
                                          .                       .     |     .           
                                          .                       .  /--/     .           
                                          .                       .  |  .     .           
                                          .                       .  |  .     .           
                                          ?                       ?  V  ?     ?           
01|08|16|19|19|24|29|29|30|33|47|49|50|60|60|60|60|66|69|69|70|70|74|75|77|77|80|81|81|91|
```

---

Also I created slightly modified infinite ASCII-screencast version of my code (download code [here](https://tio.run/##lVZLc9owEL7zK3Z6sZwYx8D0wpD01iPH9gCMR7FFEJUfYykN6fS/092VMTaQyZQZQF59u/vtQyvX725XlbPjURd11TiojXTbqikicLpQEdh3G0Eh3W6kt91mjFKnChHC4yMEP3WZV282mI8AP62drDJVIwvJstNDrEvtRDga5WoLv7UVuXQSfThV29Cr0451TWqVE@hZR5C1O/RplHttSrCrud7APWT4tSuNv5P5plOXJ300vb8yIVf7DTx2PuixxXgDRpW4XciDwJVAmFBhCBg1KNAlEOOQHDLaVEaXCvFBEO8rfcLHf7baGMG2xjAhfPA3uDDiDRhUJkfekhcuW5nPC4t2E5TNeInUDDN0uzhT2ghemeqFCbPpEB6gk07x8Y4MdKTRkUULqwAC3EEKHbFGli9KIPYOliFleOV5@eSa7ESWLHhi0lqF5catBWfNRCBMFrXLZQRnUl2BVKFdusWGUKJXGOyp2Lq8enXxW6OdEl/WyWy2@v4FyXDMmMR12eb5Q@6MHCMfpu@Jtpph54paO7ZGqVok8dTL@6RYQIb12fCSK3mma@rstcHw6lIdHGWTq33nm5l7UhGDUxNMsSYPMD3TFUmE9jadPdrYD2ow9OeT3XYtx4VteyrsPjrxwT47x5nrJkVq4wnobY/YZAOL0@MGlLEK7q8hTxeQ5COqghV8k0XUCZ8T7/GNA/K8R0asOfXOgm@9MC78DTN/z1FG/PuJ1z5RIsk8RPDADDhXC0ha/@t1EHpiVKuBy7CFjHsUefIRGgcig4dMbjZYq6NJh7prOtT5/yx/mGliza1xM9U/LuK4SfTq2Hz1ezzKn3Upm3d0K5tsJ7boMgJMl5PNi3ItSW4mOie@5d922igwNDV6uSoQIOikN/64nIcDaceyrlWZi6LXGqSx7UswQhQuWufDBPHc7OYgx2o8/ukmvmH8eIC3aoh5bpT8NepfTkTVX3GFxFEVDu5FLGZeFR7Py9gqlYvk5syZJb0K0xCliwutoEKrTH8eO0mS8IZ@b@hxgGiBDK2u9M9zejPMOmoM62tk8ZxLOMy9pQPen0lvzvuT1da@M3V524/ofSJNS@yyNOXXiDSldKVp@x7hczc6Hv8B) or or [Try it online](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67412587var2#main.py)) which produces next fast-playing video (asciinema [link](https://asciinema.org/a/412236)):

[image]

---

And one more version which uses Unicode chars to draw nice arrows and lines, also it shows much denser tree, uses more numbers to search from (download code [here](https://tio.run/##lVZLb@M2EL77Vwy8B1GJrPjRBQpvvAVaoMcc24NtCIxE23SpByh6kxQ9FHvuoYdF0R/TX9M/ks6Q1MuxsaiAxNJ88/jIGc6wejGHsli8vsq8KrWBSnGzK3UegZG5iKB@qSPIuTmM5K4FY5QakbMQVisIfpZFVj7VwXIE@Hg/aalKzXNuZc1HLAtpWDgaZWIHn2TNMm44xjCiqkNn/i49JIdSwwrGk/EH6B6UfxJW/tu5XGWZ5ITcnSO6QTabPkQ2p2uIPl3zlnFtCfw0/jDyIk91c5q/n05Rf/zvl9/xpyNrkblDPjukpWuxHxz2h8N0H5t5j396u1Mf@8ZhX7zdAPvWYX87rKFN0Pcu3F//@CVQImqjk1oYhomWEaQ@EfRoYU66gHq9lFu4hRT/6rXE/7PltjXnjT1m8vjGBV8ftxi81cFPr@McKFEgnPNnhm8M1ZgIQ8AiAwGyACoQp6lKJQuBukEQH0vZ6Ma/7qRSzPqZwOyyqUIzcu98OOGDl7nis6LDDGUL@4qElOVlDnEqpGL2TZV7S9O6DuEOWukcP2/IAe6Ni4mBavSwDiBABCm0xDQv9oKh7g08hLSva8fLbalKG7LkwRHjdS3wTCF0b/dKRcBUGvnXhwg6Um1aRC5NssNTJ1gvHXhw49pk5cnET1oawcab6WKx/nGMZOyabyHYFH6Hr3K3mhPkY@k7ot4ybENR/4hrJUTFpvHcyfukrIAcy87xg81hR1dV6Unj8qpCPBvaTZvnG9cxbCUKYtCkf445uYN5R5dNI/S3bf0RcBzkYBjPbbavVbsuLNYmsceo4eOOd7fUTOoE2U1mIHc9brMt3DefWxCqFnD7VuXjmcr0GltmDVydRVQMX@feUQ7igCIfkZG1nLtgKA7hXfBdL29nUYcpuLVrjez/r8Tu0yWqlg1jbQO0bHB@eM@WTtPJQkLtrt739qN5rCpru@UVR7ZdhqGDqRYGKwlbPWzh4SBE5w/1l2@jn9ewt5FkQwU8H9r8/yxezSQRb6rvUjZ9sx8u5yLfNwf0vcPsZH6UBdcvGJ3r9MB2GDkC3DjD9V4Yz9XWLJ1Id7ieDlIJUNSfeluWowKjnqLdwezaEFnHvKpEkbG8V3tksetLcJUkXPnowIsMw6wGYeh51IL/MuoqxNnde7Ohru3sbafu639cXTTQ1mDiDZqpSGtwV5mcY7cMB/cfTHZW5nS30bLYOzsrimshMjb1k0kYI3TtBiTqxZncS1PTnHXfvE6lTBq1VlyditScuJFlcamNLqa9iqK5QAGQFQb2rtaeDP34c04jx4EhtvUzj7P5NAyH6UOfw0JRPH/MODwvodSZHUfr520YwbQ3n1wjaPGLLNwg2/binV8VR3QZTZICazpJ7B00SSgHSeIvoS4ho9fX/wA), or [Try it online](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67412587var3#main.py)), you get next video (asciinema [link](https://asciinema.org/a/412309)), open next video image in the new tab/window of browser to see it even more nicer and bigger:

[image]

---

And another one trial to make even more advanced code and visualization. Now it is two level visualization, first half of steps is drawn vertically and remaining steps are drawn horizontally. This is done to achieve higher density of image, to put mor numbers on the console screen.

As usual, download code [here](https://tio.run/##tVhLb9tGEL7rV2wdFOJaD5N0AgSq7aIt0GOP7UEWCFpcWevwoZJU4xQ9FD310EMPQdDfUvTX9I@481gulxRlu0UqIIq1Mzvzzew3s4/du3pb5OcPDzrbFWUtdmlcb4oym4paZ2oqqnfVVGRxvR3pjRXOYbRWmSfF5aUYf6fzpHhbjRcjAR9jZ12kRRlnMY01P@Y617UnR6NEbcQPuvKSuI7BR6124OUmLdZvxKU49yWberHeRtuihKGT2clnov3A@A@Kxn/qj6dJomOUnPUlZSO5vnZFOGd/TFLuj1lL4pIAfHvgxgiu@oKqjklwCgLUU63iyKiYYK/34SvfB7WTv9//zNomXJKELPmFJTZgkn3Fst@MD1cWGIu/m3l7V/aSZe/NvI7sNcv@YFkTOIq@ZHcf/jLTXNEXLPqTRceCR9XX7ODDryYRVarULvp@H@c1qPjzkEaRMlVdRpWqPSCLnoq1oQl@SlXvy1xUy4VeiYlYw79qqeE7VbkHiitrI26MAPHuDuzEy7sVOLU68NPoWBW2BHZBL4vvPfQA@p6SUkBxCCV0LpDYvSmge5P6WEz3@iaF@op1Cia@KXIos/abdNEOKKOlMs5vlRc05TERgQMXDIEJjwpoOQswdFab4XQpzs74t52AhjVWHJpW@T5TZVwrr1RAsEolbEk6HsjLRuRFLTxENLM40Pep@XWBKRMXoqvhoQoCbvR6dhtAVR1SpB0Qy8VMrwYmGEBPYAmfBjNsGj83QM83B1KVVuooHFpMXdEKCsyxuKKx407M8uujCswXUIHvx5SYA/A9Oh5HXFUKmnKDElfTco2dsLdRSyq2TANbFScwwkRHfkBayRSkkxRypiEqEPGZfg4Zg5aKdhJqoucl/rFcwIQV8pd/arEQujGwYtq21UB1ZL2Z0pArN9RG6tMelWPBee3YFEekhWHKkLsPRki4PHWsnNo6b6japGN1AILtEQrMY@sjiI0ToI8ydEWOCRgy/j41kfX8rRwj1KzI2pJALIYBBAQAFdq5TdS8xiH8DA0hInVflwgPRk/bWW91Um8rQk39byJCBK/FJ8Q/Rm8lE2tI9tevXQizaGw5Wu@zPTJp6a9sG6SwWd4Wk6s/j3c7lSeeO2Z6oZKtdTDb1xjZ3pwWqc4VhTYWY4iZpxzQrqWZaaSq20c5qEWn3cImo8Kumur1NbsnGRy0M3XQaiIX8ALTi/0b9ptQzn/c6DSlxZAc6jawywgFzHVcb@drpVOP/kqLWzf94kzY4VBibwQLE2fTOJoX1eYFppwSuU1u0rVv2gXNlq2hOfAB18rEaSTrQ@2Gv2ts5xgJlu96av50C3kbSLu3q0zX0QZOmspzMgyH1XlVJ8W@nr8tNaT/5No/P19@fQKoKUkTMb7Ox/O7QufeEoueY33ZxvlY9GRiBlAlUo5iWEljUw6B2KT7auu1Ijxoz@nQ4zlHH5a7EbV0LTabPp25zSCrEUXYcrRbdU03mnWOEeluvS8hrbsc1ofqe8g2clCR@aB/PCAR9LCeC@4IiJa2AJs4D9p3YMhiy6TDpy6@bo1wheiGq3fTBj@fk9vEJrqMIJpZgBCdIKCQLuzvFYOcDChd9ZX8Y4g93RwttnBSQ/5PbFumA@lT0bRBjOdjRHKH2ezbIRDN8VmKF@PPHYb1IHXXdELJmNL3E1DcWHAdCJzn2asGgYPNxFi2mPDOIFFKab8Q/uAJSnj2XnLEEF1MpGQxkqUTibR6cFmSfR4ae6B/ePA6KCXL3cvLHnHD7uynFnvglDq4voi/Yam7xrZSzEWpG9Yg7gFYzBPYOgfoNgSJ2QXATH32kbX2uitzHJzp5sHx3uTuYvAfeH60UQVPNioDklvT8xtM@IwGw/kxHjFHE@45IWetz0DTbJw@EvT6SGBLeDagdNFXauvHbIbkAY5az@lCIeL/DxHe9RpQ0JITxv@vltOh4sTtQCEz8@O2H376OGYoeV776ew0H639BP@q/Qyu8mMrzR3ILrV5chpabfOc88xW5BxhXgKwg2MMPfjd6Dwu3wGsuFxvvQ2gmooS30HKW1WbIJqLydLcC7Y6VSLFQ6CT0owumxBCSVeysD1k4ezmPpA5PMUZG3cEQsbBS@NdxHkCbi47bg6fAlTK8y7MtK4unbY7p6NG/@pycEJJE2ZmQvOEhTHwC2kWw4FUdp5VgQJJkdEFQOe3PI@G5pVSiefLoX567u5Q5r5bgTWYYCbjf@ahyff9g/vaKxiT3Szju0RnPdM4u0licb8gD8v71VS4l3SuYxId@LRKctV66T0Pw@4CuYyiHMgXRfTuHEWYoCgyD8@crdHDwz8) and/or [Try it online here](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67412587var4#main.py). Resulting video is below (plus [asciinema link](https://asciinema.org/a/412388)):

[image]

Comment: Looks great from my point of view, so I upvoted.

Comment: @AlyAly12 Few seconds ago I just added to my answer one more code version and video, with unicode nice characters.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev Just updated my answer, added 3rd version of algorithm with Unicode drawings, looks even more nicer! See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZolY.gif). Almost graphical!

Comment: @AlyAly12 Just did another one algorithm, most advanced one, see end of my answer which shows algorithm in action, you can also see [its video here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GKcz.gif). This algorithm is two-level, to make it possible to put very many numbers on the screen at once. First half of binary search steps are drawn vertically, remaining steps horizontally. Thus I managed to fit 500  (3-digital) numbers on one screen. I made this algorithm for you to get an idea how it is also possible to put extra amount of numbers on one screen and how to make two-level vertical+horizontal drawing.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev If you're still interested in how things are going in my answer - I just updated my answer and added fourth version of algorithm at the end of answer. It draws most advanced console graphics, you can [see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GKcz.gif). Now I made two level approach, half of steps are drawn vertically, half horizontally, this allowed me to fit incredible amount of 500 3-digital numbers on one screen!!! See [asciinema link](https://asciinema.org/a/412388) for more longer and higher resolution video. Code is available in my answer.

Comment: @Arty yeap, looks really cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use **django framework** for the project.

1. In front end provide a form with two  fields

> 1. Array itself
> 2. The value which you want to search in array

2. Fetch the values on submittting the form and apply the binary search algorithm on input values.
3. Display the result on UI